# Поиск в таблице MySQL

Tags: mysql

Привет всем!
Есть таблица разделов кондиционеров, в ней есть раздел "Мульти-сплит-системы", ко мне приходит файл импорта и в нем часто встречаются такие названия разделов:
Мульти-сплит-системы на 2 комнаты
Мульти-сплит-системы на 3 комнаты
Мульти-сплит-системы на 4 комнаты

Я ищу по таблице по названию и если нахожу такой раздел, то все ок.
Но вот эти разделы у нас в базе это как бы один "Мульти-сплит-системы"
как бы составить запрос так что бы сравнивать до первого пробела, но и работал бы для всего названия?

Comment: Может сделать колонку `multisplit` и писать в неё число комнат ?

Comment: В Вашем случае достаточно `WHERE INSTR(ПолеИзФайлаИмпорта, ПолеИзТаблицы) = 1`. И из всех подходящих записей таблицы брать ту, где длина поля максимальна.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую